# How do I find the faulty code in android studio?

Tags: android

There is no error in the codes of my project. i am trying my project on lg g2 phone. My project opens. When I click the button and want to go to the next page, it closes. Before (2022.3.1.18) I could see where the error was in the run tab, but now I can't. How can I find the wrong line? I'm new, I'd appreciate it if you could explain it simply.

Why doesn't the run tab show where the error is?

[image]

Comment: You must be looking for Logcat window. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat

Comment: I was doing as in the photo until the update. (run tab). can i see it from logcat tab too?

Comment: yes, you should be able to see it in logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You can view this in the logcat window by applying is:crash filter.[image: Logcat view]

Sometimes crash does appear in Logcat window (don't know why), then build your app in debug mode then look for crash in Run window.